# Does Workshop Automation use Workshops?

Tags: kittens-game

The Workshop Automation perk states that Steamworks will convert resources to the craft-able tools.  I currently have 21 Workshops, meaning 126% increase to crafting output.

Does this perk take my Workshops into account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sure does!  The only thing it doesn't take into account is catnip refining.  But since Workshops don't affect that anyways, there's no reason the automation should, either.

One thing to make note of, though, is that automation only kicks in at the beginning of spring, and only for a certain amount of your resources.  So, it makes unattended gameplay more efficient, but not *that* efficient.

Comment: There's an Advanced Automation upgrade much later in game which kicks in at the beginning of autumn, thus making unattended gameplay twice as efficient (which is still not quite as efficient as if you paid attention)

Comment: Is this the reason I never saw an increase after getting the automated workshops built? At least for my Wood and Minerals?

Comment: @CanadianLuke It doesn't give a gathering bonus.  It gives a *crafting* bonus.  Wood and Minerals aren't crafted, so they won't get a bonus.  The beams and slabs you make from them, though, will.